# Node.js: recursively getting building configuration from dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, browserify

I'm developing a JavaScript project targeting browsers using the closure compiler, but lately I've been thinking to start using browserify and follow a node-like development approach: splitting the project in a number of smaller node modules,  building everything using something like grunt, using node's require system (thanks to browserify) etc.

In order to build the whole project after slicing it into some modules, I need a way to get from every module its scripts, assets, some optional configuration, and to recursively do the same on its dependencies.

Is there any *standardized* way to do this? Any module already taking care of this? Anything providing assistance to this work?

---

As requested, here an example of what i need. I'll try to pick the most complex one.

The project heavily rely on HTML5 Canvas. It's supporting [FlashCanvas](http://flashcanvas.net/), but I want it to be in a separate module because I also want to build the project without FlashCanvas support, and because I'd like to release the flashcanvas module on NPM so that it can be easily integrated in other projects.

When building with the FlashCanvas support, I need to:

- put `flashcanvas/flashcanvas.js` and `flashcanvas/flashcanvas.swf`  in the data directory that will be shipped with the project.
- Include `<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="flashcanvas/flashcanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->` in the HTML page.
- In case I'm compiling with closure-compiler, the FlashCanvas externs file must be passed to the compiler.
- Pass an option to browserify that replaces `require('canvas')` with `require('flashcanvas')`, in order to override the functions that create the canvases.
- In case FlashCanvas was depending on other modules (this is not the case for this module), take assets/configuration/whatever from the dependencies.

I believe that my problem should be quite common among who's developing with browserify: it sounds pretty normal that some modules offer assets (CSS files, images etc) that you need to include. Still I couldn't find anything to solve the issue. Is my approach the right way to structure a node/browserify project? How am I supposed to get the data listed above from my main module's Gruntfile?

Comment: Could you elaborate on *I need a way to get from every module its scripts, assets, some optional configuration, and to recursively do the same on its dependencies.*?

Comment: @KyleRobinsonYoung: added an example in the original post. Let me know if something's still unclear!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly you'd like to put submodules of your project into node modules which you want to install? IMO this is totally over engineered for a project. (Which might depend on the complexity). Further, you say `"[...] I also want to build the project without FlashCanvas support, and because I'd like to release the flashcanvas module on NPM so that it can be easily integrated in other projects."`. What other projects - your own projects or anyone's project? Please elaborate more on both.

Comment: @try-catch-finally: I'd like to build my project without FlashCanvas when targetting phone-gap, node-webkit or similar non-web targets. Currently I'm building my project with some shell scripts that take care of doing the operations described in the original post. In general I believe that the FlashCanvas thing should be hid away from the main project code. If I managed to put FlashCanvas in a separate module, I could easily use it in other projects of mine, and would release it on github to allow other projects to use it.

Comment: the dojo build system does all youre asking for. its documentation kinda sucks tho....i pity you lol